# Hide google fonts code When Selected Regular fonts in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I have add Google fonts in OpenCart site. & also, add option Regular & Google fonts for choose from admin side.

I have add below code in header.tpl file.

```
<?php
if($this->config->get('title_font')!='' || $this->config->get('body_font')!='' || $this->config->get('top_bar_font')!='' || $this->config->get('secondary_titles_font')!='' || $this->config->get('footer_titles_font')!='' || $this->config->get('main_menu_font') != '' ) {       
        $regfonts = array('Arial', 'Verdana', 'Helvetica', 'Lucida Grande', 'Trebuchet MS', 'Times New Roman', 'Tahoma', 'Georgia' );
        if (in_array($this->config->get('title_font'), $regfonts)==false) { ?>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo $this->config->get('title_font') ?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <?php }
        if (in_array($this->config->get('body_font'), $regfonts)==false) { ?>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo $this->config->get('body_font') ?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <?php }
        if (in_array($this->config->get('main_menu_font'), $regfonts)==false) { ?>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo $this->config->get('main_menu_font') ?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <?php }
        if (in_array($this->config->get('top_bar_font'), $regfonts)==false) { ?>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo $this->config->get('top_bar_font') ?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <?php  }
        if (in_array($this->config->get('secondary_titles_font'), $regfonts)==false) { ?>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo $this->config->get('secondary_titles_font') ?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <?php }
        if (in_array($this->config->get('footer_titles_font'), $regfonts)==false) { ?>
        <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=<?php echo $this->config->get('footer_titles_font') ?>' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <?php } 
    } 
?>
```

When, Regular fonts select from admin side. So, Display below code in front.

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**I want to Hide above code in front side. When, selected Regular fonts from admin side.**

What is wrong in header.tpl file code?

How can i fix it?

Comment: `$this->config->get('title_font')` is empty.

Comment: I am not php developer. I am WebDesigner. So, Can you please any more clarify for solve this query. Thanks.

Comment: *I am not php developer. I am WebDesigner.* - then hire a PHP developer and do not spam here with all that stupid questions... I do not understand why a *WebDesigner* is trying to do a *WebDeveloper*'s work... It looks the same as if I want to design something in Photoshop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$regfonts = array('Arial', 'Verdana', 'Helvetica', 'Lucida Grande', 'Trebuchet MS', 'Times New Roman', 'Tahoma', 'Georgia' );
```

with

```
$regfonts = array('', 'Arial', 'Verdana', 'Helvetica', 'Lucida Grande', 'Trebuchet MS', 'Times New Roman', 'Tahoma', 'Georgia' );
```

Empty font settings will be considered as local then.